# What's the best way to go about renegotiating my contract?

Tags: software-industry, negotiation, contractors

I started working as a contractor out of college because with my relative lack of professional experience it seemed like the only kind of work that I could find. Now I'm coming up to month 8 of my current contract for a large company which has a clause in it that says the client is allowed to hire me full time. What's the best way to go about bringing up these discussions? Should I talk to my manager, my team lead, the department head or somebody different altogether?

Comment: I'd talk to the person responsible for putting that clause in your contract, or whomever you originally negotiated the contract with.

Comment: Im no lawyer but there is a difference between being allowed to hire you, and you accepting their offer to be hired, verify this with an employment lawyer however

Comment: Get other interesting job opportunities; talk about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most companies, your direct superior will have the most influence over these matters. Whether its upper management or HR, no one is going to make a move without checking with him/her first.

Something that has worked for me in the past was to:

1. Get a general idea of how valuable he/she feels I am and if its
   positive,
2. Give them a gentle reminder that I will be forced to hit the open
   market soon before the contract comes to an end as it will take me
   time to get a similarly enjoyable working environment.
3. So if any decision regarding my situation wasn't made early, we could both end up being victims of circumstance and that
4. Putting me under full time employment will settle the issue once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a member of staff who generally oversees what you do like a project manager or team leader, then take it up with them. If you're doing bits and pieces for various people/departments then this might be a little more difficult.

In the meantime, it wouldn't do any harm to informally put the word out that you're enjoying your time there and would like to be a permanent fixture.

If you have any tangible feedback like documented reviews, emails about something that went well or such like, start putting these together as documentary evidence.

Don't be discouraged if nothing comes to pass from all of this. They might only have the budget for a temporary staff member (however good you are). On the plus side, you now of course have the experience which you felt was a barrier to you getting work elsewhere.

Very best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience: In Product based companies, mostly lies with project managers / project leaders , who in turn convey/recommend to HR team to make you as a full time employee as they are familiar of your work. It will be a strong point for you if they back you up.